# Using ng-show to have a button-click display a separate div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I'm trying to get my head around the way angular does DOM element to DOM element communication:
We're putting together a set of e-learning templates. The first interactive components we've added are a bullet (effectively a button) and a popup. The bullet and the popup can be in separate parts of the page, so they will not be within the bounds of the same directive (although there is an over-arching pageCtrl, so they have that in common).

We've made custom attribute directives to trigger loading in each component type's html template; Here's the directive for eng-bullet:

```
app.directive('engBullet', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/bullet.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // following function referenced in bullet.html
                scope.showElementByUniqueName = function (showOnClick) {

                    // remove 'replaces' element
                    $('#'+$('#'+showOnClick).attr('data-replaces')).addClass('hidden');

                    // hide all popups (in case another popup is currently visible)
                    $('.popup').addClass("hidden");

                    // show selected popup
                    $('#'+showOnClick).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

At the moment the bullet component is given a 'show_on_click' string (from the json file that describes the page content) and this is passed to the bullet template (components/bullet.html):

```
<div class="button bullet" ng-click="showElementByUniqueName( component.bullet.show_on_click )"><p>{{component.bullet.text}}</p></div>
```

The 'show_on_click' variable corresponds to the id of the specific popup the bullet should display and this variable is then used in the eng-bullet directive to show the correct popup.

If I instead added an ng-show directive to my popup template, how would I bind that to the corresponding bullet which is on a different part of the page?

I could put the logic in pageCtrl, but then I've been told controllers should be 'lean and dumb'. How would I specify which popup to show, in the angular way?

Comment: could you provide the code of components/bullet.html

Comment: bullet.html is the second, shorter snippet of code, above (the bullet template)